# What does “charge my card up” mean in this song?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

33 Days (feat. gnash & Anna Clendening)

> You stole my heart
>   Then we grew apart
>   **You charged my card up**
>   You totaled my car

Comment: Everyone just accepts metaphoric ***stole my heart*** without thinking *What **exactly*** does that mean?* I suppose the imagery in ***totaled my car*** is much the same as more familiar "made a big impact" metaphors like ***bowled me over, knocked me off my feet.*** As to ***charged my card up / charged up my card***, my guess is the "literal" component refers to ***bought things using my credit card, saddling me with debt.*** Perhaps metaphorically alluding to something like ***took everything I had, sucked me dry and dumped me***, I dunno. It's lyrics.